# MUI React SSR issues

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering

We are setting up Server Side Rendering for an existing project using React-MUI.  We have gotten everything working except for styling.  None of our CSS will load for the server side render.  Any inline CSS works fine, but any of the sheets defined at the start of the file, and bound with `export default withStyles(styles)(Page)` do not work.

Our styling is defined as follows:

```js
const styles = (theme) => ({ 
    root{
        //some CSS Here ...
    }...
});
```

Which is then bound to pour props with

```js
export default typeof window !== 'undefined'
    ? withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Home)))
    : withStyles(styles)(Home);
```

and accessed with

```js
const {classes} = this.props;
//then in render
<div className={classes.root}>...</div>
```

None of the `classes.someClassName` CSS works in server side rendering, but the second we render in browser it functions normally.  Current ideas are to try using a `<ThemeProvider/>` wrapper from MUI but any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This feels like your style sheet isn't included in your SSR bundle. Trying looking in your build files to see if any of the styles you need are in any of those files. I don't think this is handled by default. What are you using for SSR? I know that Gatsby has some plugins that are meant to handle this bridge when bundling for SSR (see [this blog post](https://galenwong.github.io/blog/2020-02-27-mui-jss-rendering/)) And I found [this post](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/ssr-with-next-js-styled-components-and-material-ui-b1e88ac11dfa) talking about doing it with Nextjs.

Comment: @ReedDunkle We are using the React-dom server's `renderToString()` method so I do not think that there is a separate bundle for that (I could be wrong I've learned this over the past few days only).  None of the CSS is included in the HTML for the SSR render though if that's what you mean.

Comment: Check out [this section](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#handling-the-request) from MUI docs. They're using the `ThemeProvider` as you said you were looking into. They import `ServerStyleSheets` and get a `sheets` object out of it. Then they use `sheets.collect()` and wrap the `ThemeProvider` and `App` component tree, and pass all of this into the `renderToString` function from `ReactDOMServer`. This is the closest solution to your current setup that I've found so far. If I were you, I'd pursue this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @ReedDunkle for the pointers on this. Ended up getting it working by using his [linked guide](https://material-ui.com/guides/server-rendering/#handling-the-request) as a reference. I ended up only needing to add `sheets.collect(...)` as well as `css = sheets.toString()` and then including the CSS in the header of the HTML doc. No need for the `ThemeProvider`, it all linked up fine using `WithStyles` now.

So basically it looks like:

```
const html = renderToString(sheets.collect(<App/>));

const css = sheets.toString();

//...
//In your SSR HTML

<head>
<style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>
...
</head>
...
<div id=react-root>{html}</div>
```